# I can't commit after push

Tags: git, github, addition, commit, git-push

I can't commit after pushing repo to github. What i'm basically trying to do is to clone some code from one github repository, do some changes and push the code to another github repository. I make some local repo, cloned the code, pushed the code to another GH remote repository and it all worked out fine, now when i'm making some changes on my local repo and i'm trying to 'add .' then 'commit -m' i'm getting this message.

[image]

EDIT:

After 'git add -A':

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `git add -A` and then tell us what's the output of `git status`? The `git add .` should add modified files though so it seems a little odd it doesn't.

Comment: @plalx The screenshot is in the edited post.

Comment: try `git add -A :/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a *submodule*.

Specifically, your output includes the following (which I had to retype, so this might have typos—try not to use screenshots if plain-text will do; this avoids manual-copy-paste errors):

> ```
> Changes not staged for commit:
> ...
>     modified:  FakeApiReqresTest (modified content)
> ```

The parenthetical phrase `(modified content)` is what tells us that `FakeApiReqresTest` is not a *file*.

The submodule in question is *another Git repository*.  This other Git repository has a modified working tree, i.e., what's in *its* working tree is not committed yet.  The *superproject* repository can only record the hash ID of *one specific commit in the submodule Git repository* per superproject commit.  The `git add` command, run *in* the superproject, will put the correct commit hash ID into the superproject Git index / staging-area, based on the commit that is currently checked out within the submodule.  (Is that confusing?  It is to me  even though I *wrote* it.)

What this boils down to is the fact that you must first:

- enter the submodule;
- view or inspect the files or changes you've made here;
- decide whether they should be added and committed, or eradicated;
- then add-and-commit or eradicate as appropriate.

The result is either:

- a *new commit in the submodule* (which you should then `git push` to wherever *it* goes: remember when doing this that submodules normally live in "detached HEAD" state, so this `git push` has one extra wrinkle you must handle), or
- a different working tree *for* the submodule

or perhaps even both.  If you wind up changing the submodule's working tree while doing this, it's generally wise to re-test the superproject as a whole before proceeding.

Once you have the *correct commit* actually *in* the submodule, and the submodule's `git status` itself is "clean", you're now ready to `git add` the submodule's commit to the superproject's index / working-tree, using `git add` within the superproject.  This may give you "changes staged for commit" by updating the *gitlink* in the superproject's index.

#### Sample commands for achieving the desired result

**Do not copy-paste these without at least reading through and thinking about them.**  Which commands you should use will depend on many things.

```
# enter the submodule
cd FakeApiReqresTest

# inspect this Git repository; add and commit
git status
git diff
git add -u
git diff --cached
git commit
<enter appropriate commit message>

# send new commits upstream before using them in superproject
git push origin HEAD:somebranch

# update the superproject's gitlink
cd ..
git add FakeApiReqresTest

# verify, commit, etc
git status
git submodule status
git diff --cached
git commit
<enter appropriate commit message>
```

Comment: That was exactly the case, it's worked. Thank you very much :)